# Extend B-2 second time

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Date of entry by land borders: Jul 7th 2021,
no stamps or cards given,
mention it's electronic
date of applying for extension May 2nd, 2022
based on verbal information by the border officer.

date of the approval notice, September 27th 2022.
(departure date of I-94 July 7th, 2022)

The date I ask to extend for is January 6th 2023.

The USCIS only updated the I-94 and merged the gap (bridge) in dates.

It can't be super clear when it started all wrong at the borders. Now I'm not sure what to do cause I need to stay until my son graduates end of December 2022. We will travel back by car.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the date to which the B-2 status was extended.  Can you edit the question to add this information?

Comment: I applied to extend until January 6th 2023 after my sons graduated and returning to Canada. they only did status change and now again I'm out of status. I think they call this a bridge. but i don't know what to do now not sure never was

Comment: The first sentence seems to say that your original departure date was July 6, 2022, and the recent edit seems to say that the extension of status was granted until July 6, 2022.  This is confusing.  To clarify, can you set out all of these dates?  (A) date of initial entry; (B) "until" date on initial entry stamp (if any -- if there isn't one then this should be 6 months after date A); (C) date when you applied for extension of status (June 2022?); (D) date when extension was approved (already given as Sep. 27, 2022); (E) new "until" date from successful extension application.  Thanks.

Comment: Two things still do not make sense after your latest edit.  First, "date of entry" usually means the day when you crossed the border, but that makes no sense because you cannot have entered on July 7th if you applied for extension on May 7th. Did you enter on January 8th 2022 or thereabouts? Was July 7th your original leave-by date? Second, you seem to be saying that your extension was granted until July 7, 2022, which makes no sense if this date was associated with your entry. What is the gap in dates? Can you add an image of your extension notice with the identifying information blacked out?

Comment: I'm sorry date of entry is July 7th 2021

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense!  I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: "can you help me?": When you entered on July 7th 2021 did you request a 1-year admission, or were you granted a 1-year admission?  If not, you were presumably admitted for the default 6-month period, in which case your application to extend filed in May 2022 was filed too late.  But if that were the case, I suppose it wouldn't have been approved.  Yet if you were admitted for a year, then it doesn't make sense for your extension request to be granted to July 2022, since that would be the original deadline to leave.  So I'm still confused.

Comment: thanks anyway I apply again to extend 6 months after I'll be back to Canada